# Bash: Overwrite previous echo command

Tags: bash, command-line, printf, echo

```
for i in {1..5};do
  echo $i/5
done
```

will echo

```
1/5
2/5
3/5
4/5
5/5
```

Is it possible to overwrite the previous echoed/printed line at every iteration? The program should echo `1/5` and then `2/5` instead of `1/5` and then `3/5`, etc. At the end of the program only one line which contains `5/5` should be left.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be achieved using a carriage return `\r`:

```
for i in {1..5}; do 
    printf "%d/5\r" "$i"
    sleep 1
done
```

I added a call to `sleep` so that you can see the terminal updating.

Note that you will need to print a newline at the end to avoid the terminal from overwriting the output.

Answer (score 2):

To overwrite a line, use a carriage return, `\r`, and no linefeed.

Try, for example:

```
for i in {1..5}; do printf '\r%s/5' $i; sleep 0.1; done
```

The `sleep` command was added so that you have time see the numbers before they update again.